# Problem with attachments on sharepoint online environment custom form

Tags: sharepoint-online, attachments

I am trying to attach a file using IE9 on a sharepoint environment on my custom webpart.

It seems that IE9 does not support some javascript API and this way I can't save my attachment...

I was searching for any plugin for doing this but I can't :(

Does anyone knows if there is a way to call the default "Attach a file" page shown on edit mode of a default edit form when clicking on "Attach a file" ribbon?

I am on a sharepoint online environment.

Comment: IE9 does not support the FileReader API.  You'll have to use a plugin that uses flash or something similar, as described in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11090097/3581857) SO question.

Comment: No other option? Is there any way to open the default Add attachment screen of a list item?

Comment: I've made some search on the internet and it seems that I'll need to handle the file attached on the server side... here is the thing: Will I be able to do so in sharepoint online environment?

Comment: You can utilize REST (or JSOM) to upload files.  You just need a way to read the files without `FileReader`.  Is it possible to upgrade to IE10/11? Microsoft will be dropping support for IE9 in January 2016.

Comment: I know that wjervis,  the problem is that my client still uses the IE9 as browser and upgrade it isn't an option at this time...